# Junit test fails when autowired is used

Tags: spring, junit4

I am trying to run JUnit test for my controller which has 2 autowired fields .
While running it, I am getting a null pointer exception on this object, hence failing to execute. I am new to this Spring JUnit test.

I tried almost all combination that was posted earlier related to JUNIT. None of them works. 
 helper and model are two autowired fields used in my test. My test goes to the controller and fails with null pointer exception. The object helper exist in my Test class, but it is null in the controller.
  Can anyone help me in finding a solution this. Below is my code

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "xml/applicationContext.xml"})
@WebAppConfiguration
public class XYZTest  { 

WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("helper")
Helper helper;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("model")
Model myModel;
DispatcherPortlet dispatcherPortlet;
@Test
public void testInitialize() throws Exception {
    DispatcherPortlet portlet = new DispatcherPortlet() {
        protected ApplicationContext createPortletApplicationContext(ApplicationContext parent) throws BeansException {
            GenericWebApplicationContext wac = new GenericWebApplicationContext();
            wac.registerBeanDefinition("controller", new RootBeanDefinition(ExplanationOfBenefitController.class));
            wac.refresh();
            return wac;
        }
    };
    portlet.init(new MockPortletConfig());

    MockRenderRequest request = new MockRenderRequest(PortletMode.VIEW);
    MockRenderResponse response = new MockRenderResponse();
    //System.out.println("helper:"+helper);
    portlet.render(request, response);
    assertEquals("tableJSP", response.getContentAsString());
 }
}
```

Can I use the autowired field created in JUNIT test class, in controller?

Comment: Why do you even need helper and model? Neither are used in your test.

Comment: I have used those in my controller. My test method calls the initialize method of controller which uses helper and model. I don't know whether I am doing it right...